# Is there a way to add 'Add to Pardot List' button on Custom related list of Contact object?

Tags: apex, lightning, quickaction, pardot

We have created a Custom related list to show only Active Contacts on Account page and we need the standard buttons like 'Add to Campaign', 'Add to Pardot List'. I am able to add 'Add to Campaign' as Quick Action on Account Page, but 'Add to Pardot List' isn't available as a button or quick action! Is there an other way to replicate same standard functionality? (in Lightning)

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to create a button and add it?
https://www.gyde.ai/kb/Create-the-Add-to-Pardot-List-Button/

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @marah - Thanks! I did come across this link before. But that's on Campaign object and I am trying to add 'Add to Pardot List' button on custom Contact related list of Account Page!